# Source of Pingbacks

Tags: pingbacks

I've replaced the default comments in WordPress with [Facebook Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-plugin/) plugin.
But I'm still getting comments in the form of Pingbacks my in wp-admin > Comments (http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/edit-comments.php).
How can I know the source of these pingbacks ?

Comment: Do you mean what site they're coming from? How to disable them? Where in the code they're stored? How they work?

Comment: Yes - "what site they're coming from" - The source of the Pingbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Not long ago I did a talk on v3.5 and posted a link to my blogpost on the company site, resulting in a pingback/trackback.

Going to the comments page I can see this:

[image]

As you can see, the title of the referring page and the link to it ( the source ) are in the first column, and the post linked to on the right